# scp for "Material Terminal"

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, terminal, samsung-galaxy-note-3

OS: 5.0 Lolly-pop
Device: Samsung Galaxy note 3

Using the terminal emulator "Material Terminal" is it possible to add an `ssh` command `scp`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a way for rooted devices.

1. You will need a binary executable of the command you want.
2. Rename it (or don't) to what you want to type in the terminal to execute it. (no filename ending)
3. Copy the binary executable to `/system/bin/sh` (root-supported file explorers can do it)
4. Change the file permissions to `r-xr-xr--` (ES FIle Explorer can, and perhaps other root-supported file explorers).
5. Reboot.

I haven't tested it but do believe it works.